# From Google Sheets to Google Calendar - Create event with info in differents cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I am in the process of learning and trying to build some things.

This is a sheet where I have to send to google calendar the dates from a reservation, the start and end, the guest name, the location, and the description or important info. Also, I would like to add to different emails, so each time I add a new reservation, these people are aware of it.

[image]

I would like to make this work but I don´t have the knowledge to do it right, so if anyone could help me out with this, I appreciate that a lot.

```
function Reservaciones() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var signup = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:D6").getValue();
var title = spreadsheet.getRange("d4").getValue();
var startTime = spreadsheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var endTime = spreadsheet.getRange("c4").getValue();
var loc = spreadsheet.getRange("c5").getValue();
var des = spreadsheet.getRange("c6").getValue();
for (x=0; x<signup.length; x++) 
{
      var shift = signup[x];
      var title = shift["d4"];
      var startTime = shift["B4"];
      var endTime = shift["c4"];
      var des = shift["c6"];
      var loc = shift["c5"]; 
eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {
      loc,
      des,
      guests: 'something@hotmail.com'
    })  
}
}
```

I tried to search for some code like this, and besides I know it could be wrong, all the codes I find are from A4:B15 for example, and I would like to specify where it is the info I want to send to Calendar.

Comment: This `var signup = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:D6").getValue();` should  probably be this `var signup = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:D6").getValues();` and I would recommend suppling the sheet name also

Comment: In your example as it stands signup is not an array

Comment: @Cooper Hello Cooper, thanks for your answer. The sheet name is "Reservaciones". I´ve already made the change you suggest, but it keeps give me this error.

Comment: @Cooper 
Error 
Exception: Invalid argument: title
Reservaciones @ Ingreso Reservas.gs:19

Comment: That is probably because signup is not an array

Comment: You should single step through your code and check each value to make sure that it is what you wish it to be.

Comment: @Cooper How do I make to signup an array? I am new to all this and still learning. Could you help me out?

Comment: Start by reading and understanding this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: signup will be an array of arrays if you make the change I suggest.  Which means you will need to indices to specify each value one for the row and row for the column.  If you ever wish to use spreadsheets effectively you need to understand how to use arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you shooting for.

```
function Reservaciones() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const calendarId = sh.getRange("B1").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  const [[b4, c4, d4], [b5, c5, d5], [b6, c6, d6]] = sh.getRange("B4:D6").getValues();
  eventCal.createEvent(d4, b4, c4, { location: c5, description: c6, guests: 'something@hotmail.com' });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly!! I appreciate a lot your time and help.